# AWS Cognito can't set credentials on CognitoIdentityCredentials

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-sdk, amazon-cognito

I'm having issue with setting credentials for AWS Cognito.

I have below code from [AWS amazon-cognito-identity-js](https://github.com/aws/amazon-cognito-identity-js) on Use case 4.

```
AWS.config.credentials = new AWS.CognitoIdentityCredentials({
            IdentityPoolId : '...', // your identity pool id here
            Logins : {
                // Change the key below according to the specific region your user pool is in.
                'cognito-idp.<region>.amazonaws.com/<YOUR_USER_POOL_ID>' : result.getIdToken().getJwtToken()
            }
        });
```

I have checked that I'm sending correct `IdentityPoolId` and `Logins` on `CognitoIdentityCredentials` method but I get undefined on accessKeyId and  sessionToken as a return.

Below is what I got.
`CognitoIdentityCredentials {expired: true, expireTime: null, accessKeyId: undefined, sessionToken: undefined, params: Object…}`

Any idea how to fix this?

Comment: Did you resolve this issue? I have the same problem.

Answer (score 2):

Assigning the result of `new CognitoIdentityCredentitals()` to `AWS.config.credentials` doesn't actually get credentials. It just sets up the credentials provider. This is why when you check the credentials the `accessKeyId` is undefined and `expired` is set to true.

If you then call `AWS.config.credentials.get()` the provider will then request active credentials.

However, another thing to point out is that you don't have to call `AWS.config.credentials.get()` in order to use a service, because each service will call `AWS.config.credentials.get()` under the hood when they are being set up.

```
AWS.config.credentials = new AWS.CognitoIdentityCredentials({ ... });
console.log(AWS.config.credentials.expired); // false

/**
 *  The dynamoDB service will call AWS.config.credentials.get()
 *  under the hood when it is being set up,
 *  so you can immediately start using services like this.
*/
const dynamoDB = new AWS.DynamoDB();
console.log(AWS.config.credentials.expired); // true
```

Comment: Hello, my friend. I have a similar question. Would you please help me to solve it? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67102738/problem-refreshing-the-aws-cognito-id-token

Answer (score 1):

After this are you calling 'AWS.config.credentials.get()' in order to make sure the credentials provider requests credentials?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you've set the **AWS.config.region**

e.g.

```
AWS.config.region = 'us-east-1';
```