# Problem refreshing the AWS Cognito ID Token

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito, aws-sdk-js

I'm trying to refresh the AWS Cognito ID Token using the AWS SDK for javascript. We need the token ID to be refreshed automatically without any action with our users. I create the following function and we will check the expiration time that is fetched after authentication and when the current time is near expiration time, we will call this function.

```
refreshToken(success, failure) {
    var poolData = {
        UserPoolId: this.initializeData.UserPoolId,
        ClientId: this.initializeData.ClientId,
    };
    var userPool = new AmazonCognitoIdentity.CognitoUserPool(poolData);
    var cognitoUser = userPool.getCurrentUser();

    cognitoUser.getSession(function (err, session) {
        if (err) {
            alert(err.message || JSON.stringify(err));
            return;
        }

        AWS.config.region = 'us-east-2';
        AWS.config.credentials = new AWS.CognitoIdentityCredentials({
            IdentityPoolId: 'myIdentityPoolId',
            Logins: {
                'cognito-idp.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/myPoolId': session.getIdToken().getJwtToken(),
            },
        });

        AWS.config.credentials.refresh(error => {
            if (error) {
                console.error(error);
            } else {
                var refresh_token = session.getRefreshToken();
                console.log('refresh started.');
                
                cognitoUser.refreshSession(refresh_token, (err, session) => {
                    if (err) {
                        console.log(err);
                    } else {
                        AWS.config.credentials.params.Logins[
                            'cognito-idp.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/myPoolId'
                        ] = session.getIdToken().getJwtToken();
                        AWS.config.Credentials.refresh(err => {
                            if (err) {
                                console.log(err);
                            } else {
                                console.log('TOKEN SUCCESSFULLY UPDATED');
                                console.log(cognitoUser.getSession().getJWTToken);
                            }
                        });
                    }
                });
            }
        });
    });
}
```

But I received the following error in my console.

`TypeError: AWS.config.Credentials is undefined`

on the following line:
 `AWS.config.Credentials.refresh(err => {`

 what should I do to solve the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is solved by using the following statement instead of using `AWS.config.Credentials.refresh`:

```
( < AWS.CognitoIdentityCredentials > myAwsConfig.credentials).refresh();
```

Here is the completed code that works and it refreshes the token ID of the AWS Cognito User:

```
  refreshToken(success, failure) {
    var poolData = {
      UserPoolId: this.initializeData.UserPoolId,
      ClientId: this.initializeData.ClientId,
    };
    var userPool = new CognitoUserPool(poolData);
    var cognitoUser = userPool.getCurrentUser();
    var currentSession = null;

    cognitoUser.getSession(function (err, session) {
      if (err) {
        alert(err.message || JSON.stringify(err));
        return;
      }
      currentSession = session;
    });

    if(!currentSession){
      failure("there is a problem with current session. try again later.");
    }

    AWS.config.region = 'us-east-2';
    AWS.config.credentials = new AWS.CognitoIdentityCredentials({
        IdentityPoolId: this.initializeData.IdentityPoolId,
        Logins: {
            'cognito-idp.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/poolId': currentSession.getIdToken().getJwtToken(),
        },
    });

    var refresh_token = currentSession.getRefreshToken(); 
      cognitoUser.refreshSession(refresh_token, (err, session) => {

        if (err) {
          failure(err);
        } else {

          var myAwsConfig = AWS.config;
          myAwsConfig.credentials.sessionToken = session.getIdToken().getJwtToken();

          ( < AWS.CognitoIdentityCredentials > myAwsConfig.credentials).refresh(err => {
            if (err) {
              failure(err);
            } else {
              success(session.getIdToken().getJwtToken());
            }
          });
        }
      });
  }
```